# How to Apply CSS based on variable

Tags: php, css

we have created a table (6x2) with column 2 containing a FA circle followed by a database field (environment in the example below) which contains the value (Outstanding, Very Good, Good, Needs Improvement & Adequate).

I want the colour of the fa-circle (traffic light colours) to be set depending on the value of field that is in that line with an arbitrary map (the correspondence between color and value will be arbitrary and set upfront).

I'm both available to have it solved server side or client side but I wish the document to have that feature where each value in the second column will have a fa-circle with a color depending on that value.

```
</h2>

<table class="tableag" style="width: 80%;">
    <tbody>
        
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 40.0000%;background-color: #ffffff;color: #f2a34f;border-top: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 3px solid #ffffff;"><b>Category</b></td>
            <td style="width: 60.0000%;background-color: #ffffff;color: #f2a34f;border-top: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 3px solid #ffffff;"><b>Rating</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 40.0000%;">Overall<br></td>
            <td style="width: 60.0000%;background-color: #ffffff;color: #000000; class = "outcome"; "><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>  &nbsp;<br><?php echo $user['rating']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 40.0000%;">Care &amp; Support<br></td>
            <td style="width: 60.0000%;background-color: #ffffff;color: #000000;class = "outcome";"> <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>  &nbsp;<br><?php echo $user['care_and_support']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 40.0000%;">Environment<br></td>
            <td style="width: 60.0000%;background-color: #ffffff;color: #000000;class = "outcome";"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>  &nbsp;<br><?php echo $user['environment']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 40.0000%;">Leadership<br></td>
            <td style="width: 60.0000%;background-color: #ffffff;color: #000000;class = "outcome";"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>  &nbsp;<br><?php echo $user['leadership']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 40.0000%;">Staff &amp; team</td>
            <td style="width: 60.0000%;background-color: #ffffff;color: #000000;class = "outcome";"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>  &nbsp;<br><?php echo $user['staff_team']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 40.0000%;">Wellbeing<br></td>
            <td style="width: 60.0000%;background-color: #ffffff;color: #000000;class = "outcome";"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>  &nbsp;<br><?php echo $user['wellbeing']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 40.0000%;">Full report<br></td>
            <td style="width: 60.0000%;background-color: #ffffff;color: #000000;"><a class="btn btn-warning btn-rg" href=<?php echo $user['cqc_url_report_english']?> target="_blank">Full Report</a></td>
            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It depends on how you generate the table. Do you use PHP / server code? Is everything in javascript?

Comment: The table was built using html.

Comment: Provide a dynamic class and apply styles based on your conditions, provide full code so everyone can give solution.

Comment: The current css is:``` table.tableag{
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #c285ba;
 border-width: 3px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
th, td {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  background-color: #47b0d9;
  color: #ffffff;
}
tr {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 3px solid #ffffff;
}

.fa-circle {
 color: #c285ba;
}```

Comment: As  you are generating this through php I'd set the stying there too. I assume that $user['ensvironment'] is just a string with Outstanding or one of the other values in it? Is that right?

Comment: There is a sql backend using phpmyadmin where the values are stored but not edited there.  This is for a directory website and will sit on a listings profile page (of which there are multiple of)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want 5 different colors, I suggest you to use a custom PHP function within your script

```
<?php

function getColor($rank)
{
  switch($rank)
  {
    case 'Outstanding': return 'green';
    case 'Very Good' : return 'yellow';
    case 'Good': return 'orange';
    case 'Needs Improvement' : return 'red';
    case 'Adequate' : return 'grey';
    default : return 'black';
  }
}
?>

<i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:<?php getColor(rank)?>"></i>
```

For a more cleaner approch, you can return a CSS class name within your function instead of a color

Comment: Thanks . I've just tried this and although the code is sound, the php code in the i string breaks the rest of the page (this is shown on the page as a widget).   Does it need anything added to ensure it only applies to this section?

Answer (score 0):

This solution will use a javascript strategy that will run client side.

You have a map defining which css class corresponds to each ranking value as `mapOfColors`.

When the page will be loaded in the browser, the code will loop through all the table rows, looking for the value of each second column and changing color of the nested `i.fa` element assigning a css class to it corresponding to its text value.

I chose arbitrary colours for each (decided upfront) ranking value.

I also took the chance to better refactor the styling of your table so that it's defined as css rules.

```js
const mapOfColors = 
  {
    '0' : 'rank0',
    '1' : 'rank1',
    '2' : 'rank2',    
    '3' : 'rank3',    
    '4' : 'rank4',    
    '5' : 'rank5',    
    '6' : 'rank6',    
    /*...*/
  }

const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.tableag tbody tr');

for(const row of rows){
  const field = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)');
  const value = field.textContent.trim();  
  if(mapOfColors.hasOwnProperty(value)){    
    const className = mapOfColors[value];        
    field.querySelector('i.fa').classList.add(className);    
  }    
}
```

```css
.tableag{
  width: 80%;
}

/*style for the header first col*/
.tableag > thead > tr > th:nth-child(1){
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #f2a34f;
  border-top: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 3px solid #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
}

/*style for the header second col*/
.tableag > thead > tr > th:nth-child(2){
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #f2a34f;
  border-top: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 3px solid #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
}

/*style for the table content first col*/
.tableag > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1){
  width: 40%;
}

/*style for the table content second col*/
.tableag > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2){
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

/*Ranking styles*/
.rank0{ color: red; }
.rank1{ color: orange; }
.rank2{ color: green; }
.rank3{ color: blue; }
.rank4{ color: pink; }
.rank5{ color: black; }
.rank6{ color: gray; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="tableag">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><b>Category</b></th>
      <th><b>Rating</b></th>    
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>    
    <tr>
      <td>Overall<br></td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        1<br>        
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Care &amp; Support<br></td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        2<br>        
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Environment<br></td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        3<br>        
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Leadership<br></td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        4<br>        
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Staff &amp; team</td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        5<br>        
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wellbeing<br></td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        6<br>        
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Full report<br></td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-rg" href="" target="_blank">Full Report</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: does it work correctly in your scenario? did you get where you need to change something to fit your specific requirements?

Comment: I had to remove some of the css changes as it broke other elements on the page but the answer to question worked perfectly

Comment: I voted to repoen the question and slightly changed the content to be less prone to misunderstanding or blaming.. but I guess it's gone anyway. Glad the answer helped.